# How to use Google Chrome Thumbnails preview service?

Tags: image, google-chrome, thumbnails, preview

anyone know how to use google chrome service to generate **web site thumbnails**? (Most viewed site on new tab).
Any idea to do a similar thing?

These:
[image]

Browsing chrome source code I was not able to find anything interesting... and you?

**SOURCE HERE**: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was: `chrome://thumb/{url}`  but i'm not sure...

**Revised:**

It's `chrome://thumb/http://www.{url}/`

Also, I found some information here [http://code.google.com/...](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)

Sorry for my English

Comment: I don't want thumbs file, i want to generate it as google do.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use html2canvas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html. It's a little buggy, and usually requires a proxy for cross-domain stuff, but if you are implementing it in a Chrome extension, you have more levity when it comes to cross-site XHR.