# Can I use "chrome://thumb/", or capturing thumbnail without using "captureVisibleTab"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture website thumbnail on my Chrome Extension.

I was examined capturing thumbnail methods, I found two ways.
1. use "captureVisibleTab".
2. use a capturing thumbnail service on web api, such as; http://www.thumbalizr.com/.

But I feel these aren't good way, because my extension use a lot of thumbnail that had been arrived.
So, I want to another way such as using "chrome://thumb/".
Is there any way to do this?

-2012/03/22
Thanks Dbz, elpsk.
And I'm sorry a too late reply.

> Can you give an example of a thumbnail you want to capture? - Dbz

I want 200x150 pictures at top-left side corner.

> similar question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/8288753/… - elpsk

Sorry, I have already read this question.
But unofficial extensions cannot using "chrome://thumb/{url}".

Comment: Can you give an example of a thumbnail you want to capture?

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288753/how-to-use-google-chrome-thumbnails-preview-service