# Get thumbnail of tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get a thumbnail of a tab from an extension?

I recall being able to do so a few years ago, but I can't find the documentation now. Is that still possible or was that feature removed?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

Comment: @CBroe this allows me to get the thumbnail of the current tab. Is there any way to get the thumbnail of each (and all) tabs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8288962/1427878 ?

Comment: Just tried it, but it doesn't seem to be working @CBroe

Comment: I think it's impossible. guess, some tabs have webcontents, and some are not (because chrome shut down old tab's webcontents). and we're not able to capture tab which is not rendered.

Comment: how about using favicon instead? thumbnail has a lot of issue

Comment: Usability. 10 SO pages have the same favicon, but different thumbnails. I want the thumbnails.